# Unclear columns of googleVis Regions Dataset

Tags: r, shiny, rcharts, googlevis, shinydashboard

What does the 3rd and 4th column( Val & Fac resp) in Regions data set signifies and how are those values obtained?

Answer (score 1):

Good question but it seems to be just **example** dataset with random values. Val and Fac are not explained anywhere.

If you write to R command line `??googleVisRegions` it is just said:

```
Val
a numeric vector

Fac
a numeric vector
```

`gvisTreeMap()` [example](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/googlevis/docs/gvisTreeMap) use them as color and size variable:

```
Tree <- gvisTreeMap(Regions,  idvar="Region", parentvar="Parent",
                    sizevar="Val", colorvar="Fac")
plot(Tree)
```

But in real life that plot doesn't make any sense. Not even these [slides](http://decastillo.github.io/googleVis_Tutorial/#29) explains Val or Fac.